# BigQuery Missing Dataset Error While Creating User-Defined Function

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I'm trying to create simple user-defined function in BigQuery using sql query like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  distance_traveled_between_time(id STRING,
    starttime TIMESTAMP,
    endtime TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS FLOAT64 AS (
  (
    SELECT SUM(fueltanklevel) FROM `eva-boa-inf2.evaboa.gpsapi`
  )
)
```

Note: this is not the real function, it's just dummy function that return float value

I think, this is a valid SQL statement, but I have this error:

`Routine name "distance_traveled_between_time" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.`

And I don't know what to fix at this point. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dataset to the name of the routine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
   dataset.distance_traveled_between_time
```

look here-^